# How does one keep hammering on another study in preprints so forcefully that one gets temporarily banned from posting to arXiv?

Tags: publications, arxiv, physics, preprint

The September 26, 2022 news item in Science [‘Something is seriously wrong’: Room-temperature superconductivity study retracted](https://www.science.org/content/article/something-seriously-wrong-room-temperature-superconductivity-study-retracted) discusses one individual who levied substantial criticism of the study, which eventually the journal Nature retracted without the consent of its authors.

> **In preprints, Hirsch kept hammering on the Dias study—so forcefully that in February, he was temporarily banned from posting to arXiv.** He also complained to the University of Rochester, which in two inquiries found no evidence of scientific misconduct. This month, Hirsch and another critic, Dirk van der Marel, a condensed matter physicist at the University of Geneva, published their conclusion that the susceptibility data in the Dias study are “pathological.” Van der Marel is heartened by the Nature retraction. “It is good to know you are not alone in believing something is seriously wrong,” he says.

**Question:** How does one keep hammering on another study in preprints so forcefully that one gets temporarily banned from posting to arXiv?

I can imagine if one posts at a kilohertz rate that could be seen as a localized DOS attack but I'm sure that's not what's happening here.

Is there an editorial board at arXiv that says "enough is enough" or "too many posts of similar nature and content" or "stop being a troublemaker", or is banning done strictly algorithmically?

Comment: I don't know the case but was rudeness and abuse part of the situation? One can get banned here for that, actually.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An earlier Science article was posted that was specifically about the "arXiv ban":

https://www.science.org/content/article/preprint-server-removes-inflammatory-papers-superconductor-controversy

> But arXiv administrators argue the decision wasn’t about science. “There are no papers in this whole chain that were rejected because we did not like the scientific content,” says Ralph Wijers, a physicist at the University of Amsterdam who is the preprint server’s board chair. “People’s emotions became too affected. They got acrimonious.”

> Papers that don’t appear to be scientifically sound or use “unprofessional” language can be rejected. Review boards then manage appeals.

Regarding one of Hirsch's submissions:

> After publishing it online in September, Physica C removed the article in November because it contained data published without the original team’s permission, and arXiv took it down in December.

And about the ban:

> Sigurdsson says he is unable to discuss the case but notes that bans can occur for reasons other than repeatedly publishing inflammatory content. Authors can also be banned for making repeated submissions in response to specific papers and contacting arXiv administrators and board members to complain—all infractions Hirsch appears to have committed.

From what I can tell, papers were rejected by humans at arXiv because they contained what they considered to be "unprofessional language", and later it seems the ban likely occurred because of many repeat submissions that fit this description. There is no suggestion that either the submissions or the decision were made by automated systems. It's not clear to me whether the unprofessional language was specifically the accusation of fraud, or whether the language went further than that. However, it does seem that arXiv moderators want to make sure that the site remains a site for posting scientific papers, and not for "blogging" or leveling accusations.

Presumably, that does not mean that arXiv is not an acceptable place for scientific criticism, but there's a difference in tone and scope between a paper that makes a *scientific* argument that a particular result is unlikely to be true (i.e., attacking a scientific theory), and one that makes an *accusation*, perhaps including personal attacks (i.e., attacking a person).

This distinction should be familiar to users here, because [Stack Exchange follows a similar principle for moderating controversial topics](https://academia.stackexchange.com/conduct), namely:

> Focus on the content, not the person. This includes terms that feel personal even when they're applied to content (e.g. “lazy”).

As a bit of an aside, I assume the question was prompted by the phrasing "kept hammering" ... "so forcefully" in the quote from the article. My take is that "forcefully" does not refer to the number or submissions but to the tone of the individual submissions. That is, the individual submissions were considered as too forceful, and that they were repeated ("kept hammering") led to the ban (instead of just rejection of individual submissions), rather than the issue being "hammering forcefully" such as by submitting hundreds or thousands of criticisms.